# Text-layout going broken

Tags: html, css

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bergi9/33x6asvk/1/).

The problem you will see on fiddle on the 2nd "separator", the text is going broken if the text is too long.
Even with the overflow and text-overflow it doesnt help :

CSS :

```css
.seperatorLabel {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="formSeparatorCon">
    <div id="sep1" class="formSeparator">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="seperatorLabel">Prüfung</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add code, your link is improperly formatted, I assume to get by the mandate that links to JS fiddle must be accompanied by code.

Answer (score 2):

Specify width to the container. It doesn't know where the overflowing start because it considers width to be 100%. Specify width in pixels. Like the following code would work:

```
.seperatorLabel {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Why not @Brewal? :) ;)

Comment: I was just saying this for in case @Bergi9 wants the width of the "separator" to be dynamic

Comment: yes, i want dynamic, but i cannot use max-width with specified pixel because the container (in this case on fiddle is the body) has dynamic width too

Answer (score 0):

after edit the `.arrow` position to absolute and remove display (with correct left and top positioning) and all containers added with max-width:100% seems to work correctly.
with little bit help of `calc()` it seems to be perfect now.

result: http://jsfiddle.net/bergi9/33x6asvk/2/

without Brewal's comment with `max-width` i wouldnt have this result